Why is this object not assignable to type using generics?
I'm having some trouble getting the return type inferred correctly in the implementation of a function.
Given the following typing
enum QType {
    One = "one",
    Two = "two",
}

type QFeedback<T extends QType> = T extends QType.One ? {
    key: string;
} : {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
}

type QContent<T extends QType> = {
    text: string;
    feedback: QFeedback<T>
}

Then when I implement this factory function. It complains about the feedback property not being assignable to type QFeedback.
Type '{ key: string; } | { key1: string; key2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'QFeedback'.
Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'QFeedback'.
function factory<T extends QType>(qType: T): QContent<T> {
    return {
        text: "",
        feedback: qType === QType.One ? {
            key: "",
        }: {
            key1: "",
            key2: "",
        }
    }
}

What am I doing wrong here?
See also this link of the code in Typescript playground.

You're looking for ms/TS#33014 which is still a missing feature as of TS5.6. Until and unless that's implemented you need to give up on either generics or control-flow-based analysis.  You can use generic indexing instead as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz excellent! very well explained and it does indeed fully address the question

We can reconfigure your types to mapped types like so. Which gives you the functionality you're looking for.
enum QType {
  One = "one",
  Two = "two",
}

type QFeedback = {
  [QType.One]: { key: string };
  [QType.Two]: {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
  };
};

const qFeedback:QFeedback = {
    [QType.One]:{
        key:""
    },[QType.Two]:{
        key1:"",
        key2:""
    }
}

type QContent<T extends keyof QFeedback> = {
  text: string;
  feedback: QFeedback[T];
};

function factory<T extends keyof QFeedback>(qType: T): QContent<T> {
  return {
    text: "",
    feedback:qFeedback[qType],
  };
}

const instanceOne = factory(QType.One);
const instanceTwo = factory(QType.Two);

instanceOne.feedback.key
instanceTwo.feedback.key1

Edit
Lol, I see @jcalz gave you basically the same answer in a playground.  His explanation will be much more informative than mine.
